# основы PHP составляем имя

Tags: php

Друзья, добрый день, продолжаю задавать вопросы по основам PHP.

Составляю имя по слогам взятых в случайном порядке из массива, застопорился на склеивание выбранных кодом слогов, в моей версии выходит только последний выбранный слог, все, что мог перепробовал, помогите с решением. Спасибо.

Пример кода:

```
$letters = array (

'ti',
'be',
'bu',
'fe',
'fo',
'sa',
'li',
'da',
'je',
'ki',
'me',
'jo',
'do'
);

$name ='';


for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {

$random = array_rand($letters);
$randomText = $letters[$random];

echo "Выпало число {$random}, слог {$randomText}<br/>\n";

    $name = $randomText;

}



echo "--------------<br/>";
echo "Советую имя: {$name} - на прогадаешь!<br/>\n";
```

Мой неправильный результат:

> Выпало число 9, слог ki
>   Выпало число 3, слог fe
>   Выпало число 4, слог fo
>   Выпало число 1, слог be
>
> ---
>
> Советую имя: be - на прогадаешь!

Comment: Попробуй так: $name =  $name.$randomText; Сейчас ты просто передаешь переменной $name по очереди значения переменной $randomText, а тебе нужно в переменной $name дописывать новое значение из $randomText.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk Спасибо, сделайте как ответ и не могли бы объяснить почему так. как в переменную записывается значения или это правило без логического объяснения?

Comment: У вас есть переменная $name в цикле на первой итерации вы в нее записываете "ki" на второй итерации "fe", на третей "fo" и т.д. То-есть каждый раз вы присваиваете новое значение переменной. В вашем случае вам нужно к старому значению переменной прибавить новое значение то-есть на первой итерации к "" прибавить "ki" (""+"ki"), на второй итерации цикла "ki"+"fe", на третей "kife"+"fo" и т.д. Оператором в php который грубо говоря суммирует  строки есть точка "." потому вместо "+" мы пишем "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так: $name = $name.$randomText; Сейчас ты просто передаешь переменной $name по очереди значения переменной $randomText, а тебе нужно в переменной $name дописывать новое значение из $randomText.

```html
$letters = array (

'ti',
'be',
'bu',
'fe',
'fo',
'sa',
'li',
'da',
'je',
'ki',
'me',
'jo',
'do'
);

$name ='';


for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {

$random = array_rand($letters);
$randomText = $letters[$random];

echo "Выпало число {$random}, слог {$randomText}<br/>\n";

    $name = $name.$randomText;

}



echo "--------------<br/>";
echo "Советую имя: {$name} - на прогадаешь!<br/>\n";
```